# Upgrade FFmpeg in AWS EC2 Linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

How can we upgrade ffmpeg in an AWS EC2 instance?
In my local system, I’m using

```
ffmpeg version N-87353-g183fd30 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
```

But in the server, it is

```
ffmpeg version N-63893-gc69defd Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jul 16 2014 05:38:01 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1).
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

## The easiest method

You can just download the binary that is already compiled:

1. Download it from https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/
2. Extract downloaded archive file.
3. Move the `ffmpeg` binary somewhere in your `PATH` or put it wherever you want and execute it directly.

## Compiling

If you want to customize your build then compile. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile Guides](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

#### Using the same version

If you want the same version* as your local system then use git:

```
git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
git checkout 183fd30
```

Then continue with one of the compile guides at the `configure` step.

<sub>*It's always recommended to use the latest version if possible.</sub>